# Burninate "development-approach"

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[development-approach](/questions/tagged/development-approach) on Stack Overflow is just... awful. Please kill it with fire.

Comment: Before removing the tags, we should consider which questions are off-topic and need to be closed.

Comment: At a glance, nearly all of them.

Comment: In that case, let's hold off on the burnination until they're all closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about burninating a tag on Stack Overflow.

Comment: (It's also already burninated, apparently.)